# What is this star next to the player name/health bar?

Tags: guild-wars-2

While running around the world I spotted a player with a star next to their name as follows;

[image]

What does this star next to the player name/health bar represent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This star is a reward for completing [100% of the whole map](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Map_completion#World_completion):

> Upon completing the last map required for world completion, a world
>   completion icon will pop up next to the loot icon. Players will
>   receive:
>
> - Normal map completion award
> - 2 Gifts of Exploration
> - The Map Completion Medal viewable from the account menu, unless already done on another character.
> - **A star next to your name, viewable by other players**